# Execute Linux shell command in c++ while hiding its output

Tags: c++, linux, shell, output

I want to execute a Linux shell command from "/sbin/" with execl or system (or another command), and hide its output.

I am using "fork" already to get a child process...

Like if I entered...

```
service "servicename" restart
```

I would see the output where it says "restarting xyz [OK]". Instead, I simply want the command to be executed silently and its output discarded instead of being shown in my console application.

Comment: This is hopelessly vague. You need to say what you're doing here. This probably doesn't have anything to do with C++. You just need to read the man pages for the calls your using. You probably want to avoid ever using `system` on user input, because it interprets it with a shell. Perhaps you just need to be reminded to reopen stdout and stderr between `fork` and `exec`?

Comment: I dont have a user input, i use a C++ Programme that restarts 2 specific services.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a shell script from C in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736210/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-from-c-in-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the output to `/dev/null`

Eg.,

`service smb restart 1> /dev/null`

`service smb restart 2> /dev/null`

where `1` and `2` represents the `stdout` and `stderr`

Comment: with a c++ command to execute it, the output shouldn't be redirecting to stdout, should it?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "C++ command"? On all unixes, child processes inherit all fds, including stdout and stderr. More, after a fork (before exec) the process is a clone, so obviously its output goes to exactly the same place as the parent. On exec, the standard streams will be re-initialised (discarding buffers etc) but the fd for the stdio FILEs will be the same after exec.

Answer (score 2):

You could append this to your command:
" > /dev/null 2>&1 "

So your command becomes:
service [servicename] restart > /dev/null 2>&1

What this does is that it redirects stderr to stdout (2>&1), and redirects stdout to /dev/null ( > /dev/null)