# system() function in C

Tags: c, debian

Will I execute shell script .sh if I run code like this:

```
int system (char *s);
int sh_exec_ok; //Shell script execution flag

sh_exec_ok = system("something/script_name.sh");
```

What do you suggest me to use to execute shell scripts in C code?

Comment: `system()` should do it finely ;)
In fact, it executes a `command line` as if you were in a shell, so that's ok. (For example you can run a `ls` with `system()`

Comment: I'd suggest you _don't_ execute shell scripts in C like that, but if your path is correct, and your script is ok, then your code _should_ work... just try it and see

Comment: `system()` can execute any shell command if it's path is correct. Donot forget to include `stdlib.h`. However, it is not recommended as it makes the code platform dependent.

Comment: @Shreevardhan i run it on Debian, and I think it will work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a shell script from C in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736210/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-from-c-in-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `system` is the right way to run a shell command.  Some notes:

- You should not declare `system` yourself.  Instead, do `#include <stdlib.h>`
- If portability is a concern, do `system(NULL)`.  If the return value is non-zero, then a command processor to handle the `system` function call is available.
- It is good practice to use the full path to the shell script, or set the path so it executes the version of the shell script you want to execute.