# Issue when opening a system file Linux in for loop

Tags: c, linux, file, system

I am trying to create a program monitor system parameter like: CPU usage percent, Ram usage percent and send a warning log when the percent is over 80%. My solution when reading CPU percent is using `mpstat` or cat the /proc/stat like this:

```
unsigned int get_system_value(char *command)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char value_string[1024];
    fflush(fp);
    fp = popen(command, "r"); /* The issue is here  */
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to check command system \n" );
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(value_string, sizeof(value_string), fp) != NULL);
    unsigned int value = atoi(value_string);
    return value;
    pclose(fp);
}

void *get_sys_stat(void* arg)
{
    float cpu_percent = 0;
    int cpu_high_flag = 0;
    int cpu_too_high_flag = 0;

    while(1) {
//      cpu_percent = get_system_value("mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12"" }'"); // using mpstat
        cpu_percent = get_system_value("grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage}'"); // using cat /proc/stat
        if (cpu_percent > 80) {
            trap_cpu_high(ar_general_config[0].general_id); // send warning log
        }
    }
}
```

And the issue is when i run program after a few minutes i will can not open the file, the pointer `fp` is `NULL`. I guest that Linux prevent a program open a file too many times or maybe can not run a bash command too many times. Can you help me explain why ? and a solution for this case.

Comment: Why are you using `popen` to call a command to read the file? Just open the file directly and read that.

Comment: Because i need the return value from the shell command. I refer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736210/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-from-c-in-linux

Comment: I am saying you don't need a command.

Comment: Actually it not only read parameter in file, it needs some command when i need to get percent of ram, CPU temperature too, so i use the `popen()`

Comment: C is a programming language that you can use to read files and perform calculations. If you are going to rely heavily other commands, you might as well write a bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    return value;
    pclose(fp);
```

and so `pclose(fp)` is never called.  Thus you leak resources (`FILE` stream, file descriptor, child process, etc) on every call, and eventually you run out so `popen` fails.

If you `pclose` properly there is no limit on how many times you can call `popen`.

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer i have fixed it. I am using this program to monitor my computer and it will run 24/24 for long time. Is there any potential issue if i get RAM, CPU percent by command like this ? I see there are some library in C support getting system parameter like `sys/sysinfo.h`, but i am not sure which way is more stable for 24/24 running computer.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen: I don't know what you mean by "more stable", and I'm not really in a position to analyze your code for all possible bugs.  If this code works, it will keep working indefinitely.  Presumably though you want a `sleep()` somewhere in your loop, or else your CPU usage will be 100% because of this program alone.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen: Note that calling `grep` and `awk` every time is certainly less efficient than getting the values by reading and parsing `/proc/stat` directly in your C program (e.g. with `fscanf`), so that wastes some CPU time as well.  Whether that's significant, and whether that efficiency is worth the time of writing more code, is something only you can decide.